# How to execute unix command after few background jobs?

Tags: shell-script, background-process, csh

My c-shell code has to complete few concurrent background jobs before execution of some unix commands. However, somehow in code my background jobs never returns handle to unix commands.

i.e.

```
$cmd1 | tee $XD/m1.log&
$cmd2 | tee $XD/m2.log&
$cmd3 | tee $XD/m3.log&
$cmd4 | tee $XD/m4.log&
```

All 4 commands mentioned above generate 4 different files named `$L1`,`$L2`,`$L3` and `$L4`(`setenv L1 $XD/div.txt` etc.). I need to merge all of these files after removing the first line from them so have used following logic. But seems like `sed` command never gets executed

```
wait $!
echo "Job completed"
sed -i '1d' $L2
sed -i '1d' $L3
sed -i '1d' $L4
cat $L1 $L2 $L3 $L4 >> $L
```

How to make then executes post background jobs?

tried

```
if (! -e $L4 ) then 
   if ( -f $L4 ) then 
       wait $!
       echo "Job completed"
       sed -i '1d' $L2
       sed -i '1d' $L3
       sed -i '1d' $L4
       cat $L1 $L2 $L3 $L4 >> $L
   endif
endif
```

but didn't work either.

```
$cmd1 | tee $XD/m1.log&
$cmd2 | tee $XD/m2.log&
$cmd3 | tee $XD/m3.log&
$cmd4 | tee $XD/m4.log&

if (! -e $L4 ) then
  if ( -f $L4 ) then
    wait $!
    echo "Job completed"
    sed -i '1d' $L2
    sed -i '1d' $L3
    sed -i '1d' $L4
    cat $L1 $L2 $L3 $L4 >> $L
  endif
endif
```

Expected results would be to generate `$L` file ( `$XD/final.txt`), which would happen only when script will be back to 2nd half section containing sed command.

In nutshell, I m looking for a way to make sure all four cmd* jobs are completed before moving to sed command in my script. Since the input of sed command, depends on output file generated with cmd* commands so they have to go in sequential order. Looking for a way but couldn't figure out anything yet.

Comment: It *seems* like the sed never executes? Do the 4 commands finish?

Comment: fwiw, `wait` in `csh` does **not** take any arguments and will wait for all background jobs. Also the `! -e` and `-f` file operators are contradictory (a file that doesn't exist cannot be a regular file). Please post a reproducible example.

Comment: `sleep 3600 & wait $!` will error out with `wait: Too many arguments` in both `csh` and `tcsh`. So you should get rid of that `$!` before anything else.

Comment: @mosvy, thanks. Sleep would be a trouble given the size of run varies.

Comment: Thanks @JeffSchaller. Yes, it never reaches to sed execution part. Wish to cluster all cmd command under some logic, which apparently would make sure the completion of them before getting to sed commands. Wondering if anyone can help me with that.

Comment: `sleep 3600 &` was only an example of a background job. My point was that you should use just `wait` instead of `wait $!`.

Comment: Thanks All. In nutshell, I m looking for a way to make sure all four cmd* jobs are completed before moving to sed command in my script. Since the input of sed commands depends on output file generated using cmd commands so they have to go in sequential order.

Comment: @user3093942 you can do that with `wait` **without** `$!`. If that still doesn't work, please edit a **complete** example into your question. `wait $!` does not work at all in `csh`.